# Why does this datetime date error comes when using strptime

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-12

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date
```

I'm getting the above error when I run the below code. Do you have any idea about this ?

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import babel
import time


date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
class HrPayslipEmployees(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'hr.payslip.employees'

@api.one
    def compute_date_diff(self, ds, dt):
        from datetime import datetime
        d1 = datetime.strptime(ds, "%Y-%m-%d")
        d1 = str(d1)
        d2 = datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d")
        d2 = str(d2)
        days = (d2 - d1).days + 1
        if days < 0:
            days = 0
        return days
```

But the same code is perfectly working in the Pythin 2.7 , but the above code is I run on Python 3.x

Imported libraries for the program are also mentioned above.

Thanks in advance. The complete code is just above here.

Comment: Where is the part you are calling this method from? Furthermore, What is line number for the error?

Comment: `from datetime import datetime` inside the method,  irrelevant?

Comment: In Python 3.x you will get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` on line 4 of your method.

Comment: Can you please tell me why youremoved that `self` from the function ?  I know that it will work without self.Why I'm using no , because I'm calling this function to some other part of the code.

eg: `month_days = self.compute_date_diff(from_date, to_date)[0]`

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to convert the `date` to `str`:

**In Python 3.x**:

```
from datetime import datetime

def compute_date_diff(ds, dt):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(ds, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d")
    days = (d2 - d1).days + 1
    if days < 0:
        days = 0
    return days

print(compute_date_diff('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01'))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
32
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why youremoved that `self` from the function ?  I know that it will work without self.Why I'm using no , because I'm calling this function to some other part of the code.

eg: `month_days = self.compute_date_diff(from_date, to_date)[0]`

Comment: @PabloEscobar I only made it shortest possible to reproduce the error, you can still do the same by just `month_days = compute_date_diff(from_date, to_date)`

Comment: If I do like above I'll get an error like this, `NameError: name 'compute_date_diff' is not defined` . Because in a class only I;m writing this.

Edited in the question.

Comment: @PabloEscobar edit the part where you are assigning `month_days = self.compute_date_diff(from_date, to_date)[0]`

Comment: Edited the entire code above in question. Can you please check it ?

Comment: @PabloEscobar that is too much code to look at, try using `month_days = self.compute_date_diff(from_date, to_date)` ?

Comment: Why do you concentrate on an error, this question isn't even mentioning? The question's error message states `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date`. Just wondering, the answer is correct but not really in context of the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"


def compute_date_diff( ds, dt):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(ds, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d")
    days = (d2 - d1).days + 1
    if days < 0:
        days = 0
    return days
print(compute_date_diff("2019-03-24","2019-03-25"))
```

This is working fine in python3. You don't need to convert d1 and d2 to string for finding days.

Comment: Can you please tell me why youremoved that `self` from the function ?  I know that it will work without self.Why I'm using no , because I'm calling this function to some other part of the code.

eg: `month_days = self.compute_date_diff(from_date, to_date)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer in Odoo context. With [this commit](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/960360afe478a8f7b9c456721b5591154952a37d#diff-4f1878356dde70c7e0aae8ab99ec2ffe) your old code isn't working anymore. Because before that, you got strings as values for `Date` and `Datetime` fields in Odoo. As of this commit you get python `datetime.date` resp. `datetime.datetime` objects instead.

So just use these objects and don't parse into or from strings if not needed.